# Source generators with a shared project

Tags: c#

I am using a source generator with a shared project (`.shproj`), but the source generator does not influence the items of the shared project, while the actual project does reference it.

I expected that the source generator would just work like normal, and influence the items of the shared project. Is there any way to make it do this?

Comment: With that little amount of information, it's very difficult to help you. Please describe the problem in sufficient detail and provide a minimally reproducible example. Also, please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from discord:

No
shprojs are nothing more than a collection of files that get added to other projects
Analyzers and generators need to run in the context of the other project, not the shproj

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).